# Calculating $a^p+b^p$ given $a^2+b^2=c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If one has $a^2+b^2=c$ where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are real numbers, is there any way to calculate $a^p+b^p$ where $p$ may be any real number? If there is, would you please explain with an example with $p=3$?

Comment: what if $p=\sqrt{2}$ or is an irrational

Comment: Not without more knowledge about $a, b, c$, or $p$. All that condition tells you is that, say, $a = \sqrt{c} \cos \theta, b = \sqrt{c} \sin \theta$ for some $\theta$, which doesn't uniquely determine the value of $a^p + b^p$ for (I think) any $p \neq 2$.

Comment: @Chandru: If $p=\sqrt{2}$ has a solution, it would be great to discuss it here as well.

Comment: A simple example to illustrate why this cannot work: if $a$ and $b$ are solutions, then so are $-a$ and $-b$. But if $p$ is an odd integer, then this gives different values of $a^p + b^p$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other responses showing you cannot find it just from $a^2+b^2=c$ are correct.  You may be interested in the fact that given $a^2+b^2=c, a+b=d$, you can form $(a^2+b^2)(a+b)=cd=a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3$ and  $d^2-c=2ab$, so $cd-\frac{d^3-cd}{2}=a^3+b^3$.  Given as many [symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) as variables you can find all the higher orders.

Answer (score 2):

There are $a, b, A, B$ such that $a^2+b^2=A^2+B^2$ but $a^p+b^p \ne A^p+B^p$.
So the answer to your first question is NO.

Comment: For example $1^2+8^2=65$ and $4^2+7^2=65$, but $1^3+8^3=513$ and $4^3+7^3=407$

Answer (score 1):

Since $1^2 + 7^2 = 5^2 + 5^2$, the number $c$ does *not* uniquely describe $a$ and $b$.  Therefore, you can get not find $a^p + b^p$.

See [Numbers which are the sum of two squares in two or more different ways](http://oeis.org/search?q=50,%2065,%2085&sort=&language=english&go=Search) for a list of more such examples.

Comment: Not exactly relevant, since the question is about real numbers.  The list *Real numbers which are the sum of two squares of real numbers in two or more different ways* is rather uninteresting.

Answer (score 1):

There are times where $c$ does uniquely specify $a,b$, which is maybe worth mentioning.  Suppose $a,b,c$ are all positive integers.  Then we can look at the [sum of squares function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) for $c$, and we know that (up to order) $a,b$ will be unique when $c$ has exactly one prime factor of the form $4k+1$, and each prime factor of the form $4k+3$ appears to an even power.

In other words, if $c$ is of that form, and $a^2+b^2=c$, $a>0$, $b>0$, then $a^p+b^p$ is completely determined for any $p$.